# Exchange Headers intermingling when used with Camel AHC and choice tag in blueprint

Tags: apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

I am using the Camel AHC component in a route where there is choice condition in the route. Depending up the value of a header the decision is taken. The route works fine during normal testing. But when used under load the Exchange headers starts mixing from when choise-when to another choise-when(happens for 1/8 number of calls). Following is my route:

```
camel:camelContext id="ZEMPSRV" streamCache="true">
<camel:properties>
    <camel:property key="CamelCachedOutputStreamCipherTransformation" value="RC4"/>
</camel:properties>
<camel:route>
    <camel:from id="_MessageFlow_20_1422954968407" uri="xyz:abc/ZEMPSRV:Employees"/>
    <camel:choice id="_ExclusiveGateway_8_1422954968423">
        <camel:when>
            <camel:simple>${header.Method} == 'GET_ENTRY'</camel:simple>
            <camel:setHeader headerName="RelativeUri" id="GET_ENTRY_Header_1">
                <camel:simple>abc/zemp_srv/Employees('{Empid}')</camel:simple>
            </camel:setHeader>
            <camel:bean id="_CallActivity_69_1422954968443" method="process" ref="abcprocessor"/>
            <camel:setHeader headerName="scriptFile" id="GET_ENTRY_Header_2">
                <camel:simple resultType="java.lang.String">Employees_REST_Read.groovy</camel:simple>
            </camel:setHeader>
            <camel:setHeader headerName="functionName" id="GET_ENTRY_Header_3">
                <camel:simple resultType="java.lang.String">processRequestData</camel:simple>
            </camel:setHeader>
            <camel:setHeader headerName="scriptFileType" id="GET_ENTRY_Header_4">
                <camel:simple resultType="java.lang.String">groovy</camel:simple>
            </camel:setHeader>
            <camel:bean method="process" ref="scriptprocessor" id="GET_ENTRY_scriptprocessor_pre"/>
            <camel:bean id="_ServiceTask_14_1422954968508" method="process" ref="abcProcessor"/>
            <camel:to uri="ahc:http://host:port/abc/zemp_srv/Employees('000000000001')"/>
            <camel:setHeader headerName="RestContentType" id="GET_ENTRY_Header_5">
                <camel:simple resultType="java.lang.String"/>
            </camel:setHeader>
            <camel:setBody id="_CallActivity_71_1422954968510">
                <camel:simple>${bodyAs(String)}</camel:simple>
            </camel:setBody>
            <camel:setHeader headerName="scriptFile" id="GET_ENTRY_Header_6">
                <camel:simple resultType="java.lang.String">Employees_REST_Read.groovy</camel:simple>
            </camel:setHeader>
            <camel:setHeader headerName="functionName" id="GET_ENTRY_Header_7">
                <camel:simple resultType="java.lang.String">processResponseData</camel:simple>
            </camel:setHeader>
            <camel:setHeader headerName="scriptFileType" id="GET_ENTRY_Header_8">
                <camel:simple resultType="java.lang.String">groovy</camel:simple>
            </camel:setHeader>
            <camel:bean method="process" ref="scriptprocessor" id="GET_ENTRY_scriptprocessor_post"/>
            <camel:bean id="_CallActivity_73_1422954968577" method="process" ref="cdeProcessor"/>
        </camel:when>
        <camel:when>
            <camel:simple>${header.Method} == 'GET_FEED'</camel:simple>
            <camel:setHeader headerName="RelativeUri" id="GET_FEED_Header_1">
                <camel:simple>/abc/zemp_srv/Employees</camel:simple>
            </camel:setHeader>
            <camel:setHeader headerName="scriptFile" id="GET_FEED_Header_2">
                <camel:simple resultType="java.lang.String">Employees_REST_Query.groovy</camel:simple>
            </camel:setHeader>
            <camel:setHeader headerName="functionName" id="GET_FEED_Header_3">
                <camel:simple resultType="java.lang.String">processRequestData</camel:simple>
            </camel:setHeader>
            <camel:setHeader headerName="scriptFileType" id="GET_FEED_Header_4">
                <camel:simple resultType="java.lang.String">groovy</camel:simple>
            </camel:setHeader>
            <camel:bean method="process" ref="scriptprocessor" id="GET_FEED_scriptprocessor_pre"/>
            <camel:bean id="_ServiceTask_15_1422954968675" method="process" ref="abcDestinationProcessor"/>
            <camel:to uri="ahc:http://host:port/abc/zemp_srv/Employees?$filter=Empid%20le%20%27000000000050%27"/>
            <camel:setHeader headerName="RestContentType" id="GET_FEED_Header_5">
                <camel:simple resultType="java.lang.String"/>
            </camel:setHeader>
            <camel:setHeader headerName="Dilip" id="GET_ENTRY_Header_111">
                <camel:simple resultType="java.lang.String">Patidar</camel:simple>
            </camel:setHeader>
            <camel:setBody id="_CallActivity_76_1422954968677">
                <camel:simple>${bodyAs(String)}</camel:simple>
            </camel:setBody>
            <camel:setHeader headerName="scriptFile" id="GET_FEED_Header_6">
                <camel:simple resultType="java.lang.String">Employees_REST_Query.groovy</camel:simple>
            </camel:setHeader>
            <camel:setHeader headerName="functionName" id="GET_FEED_Header_7">
                <camel:simple resultType="java.lang.String">processResponseData</camel:simple>
            </camel:setHeader>
            <camel:setHeader headerName="scriptFileType" id="GET_FEED_Header_8">
                <camel:simple resultType="java.lang.String">groovy</camel:simple>
            </camel:setHeader>
            <camel:bean method="process" ref="scriptprocessor" id="GET_FEED_scriptprocessor_post"/>
            <camel:bean id="_CallActivity_78_1422954968744" method="process" ref="cdeProcessor"/>
        </camel:when>
        <camel:otherwise/>
    </camel:choice>
</camel:route>
```

The switch happen after the ahc component call and by the time I come to scriptprocessor or adeprocessor the value of header.Method is switch from GET_ENTRY to GET_FEED and vise versa. Strange issue. Only happens under load testing and that too only for 1/8 of calls.

Is this related with general issue with camel header handling?
Is this related with header handling in Camel AHC component?

Regards,
Dilip

Comment: This is very similar / duplicate of your other AHC question!

Comment: Thanks Claus. We have found the solution. The problem was with one of our processors.

Comment: Ah I guess you didnt code your processor as thread-safe ?

Comment: Can you close this questions so you have found the solution?